# Create Select distinct query with criteria of having the latest date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been struggling with creating a query in Access to select a distinct field with the criteria of having the newest entry in the database.

Heres a brief summary of how what my table conssists of.  I have a table with surveying data collected from 2007 to the present.  We have field with a survey marks name with corresponding adjustment data.  In the corresponding data there is field with the adjusmtent date.  Many of the marks have been occupied mutiple times and only want to retrieve the most recent occupation information.

Roughly i want to

```
SELECT DISTINCT STATUS_POINT_DESIGNATION
FROM __ALL_ADJUSTMENTS
WHERE [__ALL_ADJUSMENTS]![ADJ_DATE]=MAX(ADJ_DATE)
```

I seem to be getting confused how relate the select a distinct value with a constraint.  Any Suggestions?

DH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you could achieve your aim of getting the latest observation for each survey point by a summary function:

```
SELECT STATUS_POINT_DESIGNATION, Max(ADJ_DATE) AS LatestDate, Count(STATUS_POINT_DESIGNATION) AS Observations
FROM __ALL_ADJUSTMENTS
GROUP BY STATUS_POINT_DESIGNATION;
```